# R Shiny: write image from r shiny input to sql then render

Tags: r, shiny

ui

[image]

```r
tabItem(tabName="imageinput",
                          box(status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = TRUE,
                              width = 12,                     textInput("ContactName",label=NULL,placeholder="Enter Contact Name"),
                              `enter code here`textInput("ContactEmail",label=NULL,placeholder="Enter Contact Email"),
                              textAreaInput("Comments", label = "Describe Activity:",placeholder = NULL)
                      ,
                          fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload...", multiple = FALSE),
                      actionButton("GoPost", "Submit Suspicious Activity", style = "font-family: 'Palatino', Arial Black;"),
                      column(width=12,
                             fluidRow(box(column(width=12,(DT::dataTableOutput("tableForum")))
                             ))
                      ),
                          renderImage("img2",deleteFile = FALSE)))
```

this is what i have to insert name, email comments and photoupload
the below will take the image but every time i try to insert into the query to paste to the db, it says there is sql query error.. can someone please help

Warning: Error in new_result: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=4].
[No stack trace available]

```r
   qryForum = paste0("INSERT INTO imagetable (ContactName,ContactEmail,Comments,photoupload)",
                      "VALUES ('",paste(input$ContactName,"'",",","'",input$ContactEmail,"'",",","'",input$Comments,"'",",","'",input$upload"')"))
    ###Query to send to database
    dbSendQuery(my.db,qryForum)
    querygetForum <- paste("select * from imagetable;")
    dataForum <- dbGetQuery(my.db, querygetForum)`
```

Comment: what error? it helps to not have to guess

Comment: btw, inserting data that way is horrible, why not use `DBI::dbWriteTable`?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:shiny]? It seems your problem is with the database connection, not any shiny components.

Comment: essentially, i want users to be able to post name, email, comments and a photo and then render all those in the database - like a forum for suspicious activity.. i have the input in my ui for all inputs @r2evans

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have a beautiful and fully-functional shiny interface, the problem you're allegedly having here is with the database connection, nothing more. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Warning: Error in new_result: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=4].
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: Please put that in your question. Comments are easily skipped by readers or hidden by Stack's interface.

Comment: If you can do it in this fashion on your R console, then I suggest you add `browser()` in this `reactive` (or `observe`) block of your shiny server component, then try to do it interactively from within the executing shiny app. Is it possible that this is triggering before the data is stable?

Comment: can you email me? kristina.s.paterson@gmail.com

Comment: I don't do it that way, sorry Kristina. Some suggestions for your code: (1) either replace `dbSendQuery` with `dbExecute`, *or* use `res <- dbSendQuery(...); dbClearResult(res);`. (2) Really, though, use `dbWriteTable` or `dbAppendTable`, they are intended for this. (3) Your "insert" code mentions four columns but you only include three `input$` variables, perhaps you should remove `photoupload` from the list of columns to insert into. (4) I suggest you read more about DBI at https://db.rstudio.com/ and https://db.rstudio.com/.

Comment: the table is empty, just has the 4 columns, i've removed the photoupload and added it back in.. just thought it would be easier on sharescreen .. the problem is in the paste values in the sql query, it works without the image but it's expecting the list(src,contenttype, width,height) in R i believe.. i want to input 4 columns, i've tried having 4 inputs/values in the query but that field will not load values

Comment: It doesn't matter if a table has 4 or 400 columns, if you only want to insert 3 columns then you only list those 3 column names on an insert.

Comment: ive updated the question to see all code for that section

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Have you ever looked at `input$upload`? It isn't something you can `paste` into a SQL string and insert. `input$upload` will be a `data.frame` that includes columns `"name"`, `"size"`, `"type"`, and `"datapath"`. Like I suggested before, add `browser()` before you create `qryForum`, run your app, and then look at `input$upload`.

Comment: I suggest you read [`?shiny::fileInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/fileInput.html).

Comment: no is there a line i can add that will read and output the image first

Comment: at this point id be fine just being able to render the image, i have an image in one of my tabs but would like to be able o at least upload and displlay